# Meta-Tag in many Languages

Tags: html, seo

Is it helpful to improve of SEO, when I write Meta-Tag in many languages ?
Is it helps to search engines to find description of site in other languages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting users in a couple specific countries, it can be helpful to have metas in multiple languages. A couple ways to do this:

1. Depending on what CMS you are using (if you are using a CMS) you can get multiple language SEO plugin that will help generate SEO tags for you.
2. You can add custom meta tags with descriptions directing for each specific type of language you would like to use (i.e. `<meta name="description" lang="DE" content="Germany description.">`

For larger scale projects the your best route would actually be to buy country specific domains (i.e. yoursite.fr, yoursite.uk). Article on that topic here: http://searchengineland.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-multilingual-and-multiregional-seo-157838

**BIG BUT**: Google does not make it easy for you to target separate countries using SEO on one page. Anecdotal evidence suggest it will rank you on one language, and not do as great regardless of linking, etc. on other languages.

For the future, MOZ is great about producing current content re: any SEO questions.